# Estimator of a censored exponential

Tags: self-study, estimators, censoring

I am trying to self-study the MIT OpenCourseware course on Statistics, here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-650-statistics-for-applications-fall-2016/syllabus/

On [problem set 4](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-650-statistics-for-applications-fall-2016/assignments/MIT18_650F16_PSet4.pdf), question 3 is about censored data:

> In a given population, $n$ individuals are sampled randomly, with replacement, and each sampled individual is asked whether his/her salary is greater than some fixed threshold $z$. Assume that the salary of the randomly chosen individual has the exponential distribution with unknown parameter $\lambda$. Asking whether the salary overcomes a given threshold rathen than directly asking for the salary increases the number people that are willing to answer and decreases the number of mistakes in the collected answers. Denote by $X_1,...,X_n$ the binary responses ($X_i \in {0,1}, i=1,...,n)$ of the $n$ sampled individuals.

These are the questions and my answers so far:

**What is the distribution of the $X_i$'s?**

The distribution is Bernoulli with parameter $e^{-\lambda z}$

**Let $\bar{X_n}$ be the proportion of sampled individuals whose response was 1 (corresponding to Yes). Prove that $\bar{X_n}$ is asymptotically normal and compute the asymptotic variance.**

From the CLT, $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X_n}-\mu) \xrightarrow{\text{(d)}} N(0,\mu (1-\mu))$ where $\mu$ is the expectation of $X_i$, $e^{-\lambda z}$. So $\bar{X_n} \xrightarrow{\text{(d)}} N(\mu, \frac{\mu(1-\mu)}{n})$ and the asymptotic variance is $\frac{\mu(1-\mu)}{n}$.

**Find a function $f$ such that $f(\bar{X_n})$ is a consistent estimator of $\lambda$**

From the law of large numbers, $\bar{X_n} \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} e^{-\lambda z}$ and $f(x)=-\frac{\ln{x}}{z}$ is a continuous function
so from the continous mapping theorem we have $f(\bar{X_n}) \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}}\lambda$ so this is a consistent estimator.

**Prove that $f(\bar{X_n})$ is asymptotically normal and compute the asymptotic variance**

This is where I am stuck. My estimator involves the log of something that converges in distribution to a Gaussian, which does not seem to converge to a Gaussian to me.

Could I have a hint for what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Please add `self-study` as a tag. And provide the details of the question rather than linking to it.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post to comply with the suggestions.

Comment: The [Delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) could help.

Comment: @Xi'an Ah, fantastic! I completely forgot about the Delta method, thank you for the hint! I actually realized that my estimator is the MLE estimator, which I know converges (under certain conditions) to a Gaussian with variance equal to the inverse of the Fisher information.


The Delta method helps a lot as I wasn't sure how I would do it if I didn't realize it was the MLE estimator. I get the same asymptotic variance computing it both ways, which gives me some confidence in my answer. If you want to put your comment in an answer, I would accept it.